# How to root without triggering Knox?

Tags: rooting, root-access, samsung-knox, warranty

I wonder, how do I root a Samsung phone without triggering Knox? Because not only the warranty gets voided, also some Samsung apps don't open.

Comment: I never experimented with a Samsung device but this quote from Magisk [documentation](https://github.com/topjohnwu/Magisk/blob/f8b4190a11fc5dd3a5c7162d72a27b5bf174ef4a/docs/install.md#L76): *“Installing Magisk **WILL** trip KNOX”*.

Comment: OK, but I need it to be installed and I just want that my Samsung apps don't become trash. Warranty is not the case.